# How to convert oracle.jms.AQjmsAdtMessage type to string or xml in mule flow

Tags: mule, oracle-aq

I am receiving message from oracle AQ queue using JMS connector in mule, but the message type is oracle.jms.AQjmsAdtMessage. How to access the payload in mule flow.

Answer (score 0):

Use byte array to string transformer or object to XML transformer

```
<byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
```